# Organização de DIVs

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema para organizar as `divs` de um projeto.

Criei uma página de *login* de HotSpot apenas *mobile*, ela tem a resolução de um celular. Só que ela possui um *background* (*image*) e um *background* *cover* (gradiente) por cima da imagem. E todo conteúdo que eu coloco dentro dessa `div` fica por baixo do gradiente (herdando assim sua cor)

Além disso não consigo posicionar essa nova `div` de forma com que ela fique como um rodapé fixo na página (lembrando que ela é do tamanho de uma tela de celular apenas, ou seja, o `footer` tem que ficar visível apenas nesse espaço.

Segue exemplo de como ela está e como preciso que fique (respectivamente)

[image: Comparativo]

Meu código:

```css
/* BASE */

*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  -webkit-transition: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -khtml-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#form-container {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#form-container #conversion {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* FIELDS */

#conversion section div.field,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form div.field {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 12px 0;
}

#conversion section div.field div,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form div.field div {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form select,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form textarea,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form .select2-choice,
#conversion section input,
#conversion section select,
#conversion section textarea,
#conversion section .select2-choice {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#conversion section .select2-choice {
  height: 34px;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form label,
#conversion section label {
  display: block;
  min-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form select,
#conversion section select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form textarea,
#conversion section textarea {
  height: 104px;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input[type=radio],
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input[type=checkbox],
#conversion section input[type=radio],
#conversion section input[type=checkbox] {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: inherit;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input[type=radio]+label,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input[type=radio]+label+label,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input[type=checkbox]+label,
#conversion section input[type=radio]+label,
#conversion section input[type=radio]+label+label,
#conversion section input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 0 4px 28px;
}


/* SOCIAL PAY */

#conversion section div#pay-area {
  padding: 16px 0 0 0;
}

#conversion section div#pay-area p {
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* CALL TO ACTION */

#conversion-modal .modal-content section div.actions,
#conversion section div.actions {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 0 8px 0;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section div.actions .call_button,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section div.actions a.call_button,
#conversion section div.actions .call_button,
#conversion section div.actions a.call_button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-break: break-word;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 2px auto 24px auto;
  padding: 15px 20px 17px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section div.actions img,
#conversion section div.actions img {
  width: auto !important;
}


/* ERROR */

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form label.error,
#conversion section label.error {
  display: none !important;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section form input.error,
,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form textarea.error,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form .select2-container.error .select2-choice,
#conversion-modal .modal-content section form select.error,
#conversion section input.error,
#conversion section textarea.error,
#conversion section .select2-container.error .select2-choice,
#conversion section select.error {
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section div#error-container,
#conversion section div#error-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
  margin: 0 0 24px 0;
  padding: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#conversion-modal .modal-content section div#error-container p,
#conversion section div#error-container p {
  color: #463A33;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* SELECT 2 */

.select2-container {
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-width: 1px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px !important;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow b {
  background-position: 0 5px;
}

.select2-drop-active {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

</style><style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
/* SPECIFIC CONVERSION FORM */

#form-container #conversion header {
  padding: 30px;
}

#form-container #conversion header h1 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

#form-container #conversion header h2 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#form-container #conversion section {
  padding: 20px;
}

#form-container #conversion #conversion-form div.actions input.call_button {
  margin: 0;
}

#conversion #conversion-form p.notice {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  word-break: break-word;
}


/* VARIABLES */

#conversion {
  background-color: #27528f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 660px;
}

#conversion header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#conversion header h1,
#conversion header h1 a {
  color: #27528f;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#conversion header h2,
#conversion header h2 a {
  color: #27528f;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#conversion form input,
#conversion form select,
#conversion form .select2-container,
#conversion form textarea {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#conversion form label,
#conversion form p.notice,
#conversion form p.notice a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#conversion div.actions .call_button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

#conversion div.actions .call_button:not(.editable):hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}


/* BOOTSTRAP */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: roboto;
  display: flex;
  /* You delete it on your web page */
  justify-content: center;
  /* and this - delete */
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

.login-card {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Pyb7Alw.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -wenkit-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: roboto!important;
}

.login-card:after {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, rgb(159, 194, 211), rgb(63, 81, 181));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-135deg, rgb(159, 194, 211), rgb(63, 81, 181));
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 3;
}

.login-card>form {
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-kapsul {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.8;
  size: 100%;
}

.logo-kapsul h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #336;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.logo-kapsul h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.logo {
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}


/* form başlangıç stiller ------------------------------- */

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.group input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: none;
  color: #eee;
}

.group input:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* LABEL ======================================= */

.group label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}


/* active durum */

.group input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}


/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}

.group input:focus~.bar:before,
.group input:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.group input:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

.input-ikon {
  font-size: 25px!important;
  position: relative;
}

.input-sifre-ikon {
  font-size: 22px!important;
  position: relative;
}

.span-input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

.giris-yap-buton,
.kayit-ol-buton,
.sifre-hatirlat-buton {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, rgb(159, 194, 211), rgb(63, 81, 181));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-135deg, rgb(159, 194, 211), rgb(63, 81, 181));
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.forgot-and-create {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.forgot-and-create a {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.zaten-hesap-var-link {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 login-card">


  <form id="sifre-hatirlat-form" class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="col-lg-12 logo-kapsul">
      <img width="100" class="logo" src="http://www.wdcnet.com.br/marketing/hot-spot-visitante/wdc_logo-final.png" alt="WDC Networks - WiFi" alt="Logo" /><br />
      <p>
        <h1>Bem Vindo</h1>
      </p>
      <h2>Quase tudo pronto! Precisamos apenas de mais algumas informações antes de liberarmos seus acesso.</h2><br /><br />
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="group">
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label><i class="material-icons input-ikon">mail_outline</i><span class="span-input">E-Mail*</span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label><i class="material-icons input-ikon">phone_outline</i><span class="span-input">Celular*</span></label>
    </div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sifre-hatirlat-buton">Conectar</a>

    <a class="zaten-hesap-var-link">Prometemos não utilizar suas informações de contato para enviar qualquer tipo de SPAM.</a>

  </form>



</div>
```

Comment: [edit] sua pergunta e adicione o html e css utilizados.

Comment: Pronto.. coloquei em um link externo com o código